# How can I resolve the unmet dependencies error while installing Rabbitmq 3.7.4 with Erlang/OTP 20 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

I'm currently trying to install RabbitMQ version 3.7.4 with Erlang/OTP 20 on Ubuntu 16.04. This specific version combination has been working for me. However, when I attempt to install it, I encounter the following error:

```
`The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
rabbitmq-server : Depends: erlang-base (< 1:24.0) but it is not going to be installed or
erlang-base-hipe (< 1:24.0) or
esl-erlang (< 1:24.0)
Depends: erlang-crypto (< 1:24.0) or
esl-erlang (< 1:24.0)
Depends: erlang-eldap (< 1:24.0) but it is not going to be installed or
esl-erlang (< 1:24.0)
Depends: erlang-inets (< 1:24.0) or
esl-erlang (< 1:24.0)
Depends: erlang-mnesia (< 1:24.0) or
esl-erlang (< 1:24.0)
Depends: erlang-os-mon (< 1:24.0) or
esl-erlang (< 1:24.0)
Depends: erlang-parsetools (< 1:24.0) or
esl-erlang (< 1:24.0)
Depends: erlang-public-key (< 1:24.0) or
esl-erlang (< 1:24.0)
Depends: erlang-runtime-tools (< 1:24.0) or
esl-erlang (< 1:24.0)
Depends: erlang-ssl (< 1:24.0) or
esl-erlang (< 1:24.0)
Depends: erlang-syntax-tools (< 1:24.0) or
esl-erlang (< 1:24.0)
Depends: erlang-tools (< 1:24.0) or
esl-erlang (< 1:24.0)
Depends: erlang-xmerl (< 1:24.0) or
esl-erlang (< 1:24.0)`
```

I have attempted various solutions, but none of them seem to be working. The issue arose when I tried to update my Ubuntu server, which resulted in an update to Erlang. After the update, RabbitMQ stopped working. Can anyone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue? Thank you.

Regards

Comment: Don't use out-of-date, unsupported versions of RabbitMQ, Erlang and Ubuntu.